# React Navigation, close stack navigation inside Drawer navigation by clicking on drawer item

Tags: react-native, navigation, reset

I have small issue with react navigation v6...

Drawer Navigation:

```
<Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={(props) => <CustomDrawer {...props} />} >
    <Drawer.Screen name="Search" component={MainStackNavigator} />
    <Drawer.Screen name="Contact" component={ContactScreen} />
</Drawer.Navigator>
```

Stack navigation:

```
const MainStackNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="OffersList">
      <Stack.Screen name="OffersList" component={OffersList} />
      <Stack.Screen name="OfferDetails" component={OfferDetails} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

and now, when I click on the element **Search** in drawer navigation then `OffersList` page is displayed. Next, on the `OffersList`, when I click on any offer link, then I see `OfferDetails` view (Stack Navigation) - every thing is ok. Then, when I click on the **Contact** in drawer nav, and again on **Search** then I see last opened OfferDetails instead of `OfferList`. How can I reset this stack navigation when i navigate by drawer?

Answer (score 1):

The user doesn't expect a stack reset, but you think it improves the app experience, just pass `unmountOnBlur: true` on `screenOptions` for the Drawer. Your code will be like this:

```js
function MyDrawer() {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        unmountOnBlur: true
      }}
    >
      <Drawer.Screen name="SomeScreen" component={SomeScreen} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="SomeStack" component={SomeStack} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}
```

You can see the complete example code on an Expo snack. https://snack.expo.dev/@marcelofreires/stackoverflow-questions-71548781

Comment: This option unfortunately doesn't blur stack navigation inside drawer navigation :/

Comment: Hello @MichalM! I added a link to the full example code on the answer. Check if it resolves your problem. https://snack.expo.dev/@marcelofreires/stackoverflow-questions-71548781

Answer (score 0):

I have the same requirement and I use the [useIsFocused](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-is-focused) hook, in all screens inside the stack except the initial screen I use useEffect to check if `isFocused` is false then pop the screen out. Here is the example code.

```
import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native'

function Sample({navigation}) {
  const isFocused = useIsFocused()
  
  // When the screen is blured, pop it out so when user goes back they will always see the initial screen
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isFocused) {
      navigation.pop()
    }
  }, [navigation, isFocused])
}
```